# Show NSMenu next to NSButton in Swift macOS

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

How can I show a `NSMenu` next to my `NSButton` after the button was clicked?

This is what I have so far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var BtnMenu: NSButton!

// Menu
let appMenu = NSMenu()
let showPrefsMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Preferences...", action: #selector(VC.showPrefs(_:)), keyEquivalent: "")
let showAboutMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "About", action: #selector(VC.showAbout(_:)), keyEquivalent: "")
let quitAppMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: #selector(VC.quitApp(_:)), keyEquivalent: "")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set up menu
    self.appMenu.addItem(self.showPrefsMenuItem)
    self.appMenu.addItem(self.showAboutMenuItem)
    self.appMenu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separatorItem())
    self.appMenu.addItem(self.quitAppMenuItem)
}

// Shows the app menu
@IBAction func openMenu(sender: NSButton) {
    self.appMenu.popUpMenuPositioningItem(self.appMenu.itemAtIndex(0), atLocation: NSEvent.mouseLocation(), inView: nil)
}
```

But right now, the menu is shown on mouse position. Is there a way to show the menu next to the button?

Thanks.

Comment: https://onmyway133.github.io/blog/How-to-show-context-menu-from-NSButton-in-macOS/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```swift
let p = NSPoint(x: sender.frame.origin.x, y: sender.frame.origin.y - (sender.frame.height / 2))
self.appMenu.popUp(positioning: nil, at: p, in: sender.superview)
```

In this case the menu is displayed under the clicked button.

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3.

Show NSMenu under the button:

```swift
    let p = NSPoint(x: 0, y: sender.frame.height)
    appMenu.popUp(positioning: nil, at: p, in: sender)
```

Show NSMenu to the right of the button:

```swift
    let p = NSPoint(x: sender.frame.width, y: 0)
    appMenu.popUp(positioning: nil, at: p, in: sender)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let p = NSPoint(x: sender.frame.origin.x, y: sender.frame.origin.y)
self.appMenu.popUpMenuPositioningItem(self.appMenu.itemAtIndex(0), atLocation:p , inView: nil)
```

Comment: No. `atLocation` needs a `NSPoint`, but sender.frame is `NSRect`, so it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

There only missing to pass the sender button.

From john elemans response:

```
 let p = NSPoint(x: sender.frame.origin.x, y: sender.frame.origin.y)
 self.appMenu.popUpMenuPositioningItem(self.appMenu.itemAtIndex(0), atLocation:p , inView: sender)
```